# react native event when first opened

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the correct event for the first start up in a react native app.

I understand AppState and can get these statuses from the React Native Docs

> App States
>   active - The app is running in the foreground
>
> background - The app is running in the background. The user is either
>   in another app or on the home screen
>
> inactive - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between
>   foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as
>   entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call

In the docs it mentions that when the app first loads AppState.currentState will be null, but I can find when that would happen.

Why do I even care you ask, I am trying to send a "login" event, but I don't want it every time the app becomes active. If it is relevant I am working on a cross platform app, both Android and IOS need to be supported.